# Facebook Comments Box Moderation

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Having a problem setting up the moderation toolkit on my facebook comments plug-in. I am trialling this on one page at the moment until I copy it to all pages to each have their own individual comments boxes.

Site Page: http://gp2aus.com/why-go.html

I have inserted the following after my *head* tag:

```
<!-- Facebook Comments Box App ID -->
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="{100016298409099}"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{1321908721223176}" />
```

The following comes after the opening of the *body* tag:

```
<!-- Facebook Comments Box Script -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=1321908721223176";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the following is in the correct location on my page within the *body* tag:

```
<!-- Facebook Comments Box -->
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://gp2aus.com/why-go.html" data-width="100%" data-numposts="100" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

I have tried all of the applicable solves I have found on SO.

- My AppID is correct
- AppID's match in the script and AppID pages
- I am listed as a moderator in the Settings in the 'Tools & Support' section
- I am not in the banned or blacklisted sections!

One thing that I wonder is the problem, but don't know how to fix, is that when I open the 'Facebook for Developers' site and click on the 'Tools & Support' it says that there are no comments for review. Which is odd given that I have just tried making some example comments from myself and another profile and nothing seems to come up.

Can't quite see what I'm doing wrong here but would much appreciate your collective wisdom!

S.

Comment: `{}` are used in the documentation to show that you need to insert a value at this point; they are not part of that value. Fix that, and then use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to refresh the cache and check for further errors.

Comment: Very helpful. I didn't realise that! Thanks CBroe. I didn't realise to use the debugger either. Interestingly enough it's thrown up lots of little comments about bugs. I hadn't included any meta data at all! Also, I didn't know what meta data was at all! I've just done a lot of reading, read YOUR previously very helpful comments on correcting peoples meta data and I've finally fixed it. Moderation tools all working. Please feel free to repost your answer so I can put as the solution to this problem - thanks CBroe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` are used in the documentation to show that you need to insert a value at this point; they are not part of that value.

If you see f.e. `{app-id}` in there, it means you need to replace the whole placeholder `{app-id}` with the actual app id, not just put it inside the curly braces.

Fix that, and then use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to refresh the cache and check for further errors.